# javascript match a string from list of url in array and get that value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a variable as `var input = 'promojam-untitled-promotion-2';` and an array

```
var prefferedPatterns = [
  "https://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-2",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-3",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-4",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-5",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-6",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-7",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-8",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-9"
]
```

I have to find the matched input element from this array. any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? `for`, `indexOf`, `filter`, RegEx, ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3074700/finding-matching-string-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to loop through array and search `input` in current value using `indexOf()`.

Following is a sample code using `.filter()`

```js
var input = 'promojam-untitled-promotion-2';

var prefferedPatterns = [
  "https://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-2",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-3",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-4",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-5",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-6",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-7",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-8",
  "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-9"
]

var output = prefferedPatterns.filter(function(item){
  return (item.indexOf(input)>0)
})

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
var input = 'promojam-untitled-promotion-2';
var prefferedPatterns = [
    "https://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-2",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-3",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-4",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-5",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-6",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-7",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-8",
    "http://promojam.live.promojam.dev:5000/promojam-untitled-promotion-9"
     ]
      for (var i = 0; i < prefferedPatterns.length; i++) {
        if (prefferedPatterns[i].indexOf(input) > -1) {
        alert(prefferedPatterns[i]);
      }
     }
```